# C - WinAPI: Why does UTF-8 encoded characters show as Chinese in Listview?

Tags: c, listview, winapi, encoding

Trying to add text to a listview.
Code appears as Chinese characters despite multiple attemps to correctly use encoding.
Summary of the code from json file to listview:

```
// json file (UTF8 without BOM)
"name": "abcdefghijklmnop" // shows as Chinese
// "name": "ササササササササササ" // Japanese does not show correctly neither

// declare structure and array; malloc array later
struct user {
    char* name;
    // char[16] name;
};
struct user *users;

// read from json
cJSON* json_name = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(json_user, "name");

// set name (in a loop)
users[i].name = json_name->valuestring;

// create listview
HWND hWndListView = CreateWindowExW(NULL,
    WC_LISTVIEW,
    L"Test Listview",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
    // ...

// add column definitions
LVCOLUMN lvc = { 0 };
lvc.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_FMT;
lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;

// column example
lvc.iSubItem = 0;
lvc.cx = 100;
lvc.pszText = TEXT("A");
ListView_InsertColumn(hWndListView, 0, &lvc);

// debug: check it's unicode
BOOL what = IsWindowUnicode(hWndListView); // 1

// debug
#ifdef UNICODE
    int i = 0; // this is executed
#endif
```

What I have tried:

```
ListView_SetItemText(hWndListView, 2, 1, servers[0].name);         // chinese
ListView_SetItemText(hWndListView, 2, 1, *servers[0].name);        // access violation
ListView_SetItemText(hWndListView, 2, 1, (LPWSTR)servers[0].name); // chinese
ListView_SetItemText(hWndListView, 2, 1, L"%s", servers[0].name);  // %s
ListView_SetItemText(hWndListView, 3, 0, TEXT(servers[0].name));   // does not compile
```

In VS2019 debugger, adding a watch with the "s8" parameter to see the result as UTF8 correctly displays the text.
It is only when added in the control that it does not appear correctly.
Note that this works:

```
ListView_SetItemText(hWndListView, 2, 2, TEXT("ササ"));
```

Question: what am I missing for my data to be correctly displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing in commonly known as "Mojibake". It happens when 8-bit character data is *misinterpreted* as 16-bit Unicode data.

You are creating a Unicode window for your ListView, due to your use of `CreateWindowExW()`. As such, you must give the ListView proper UTF-16 encoded text using `wchar_t` characters, but you are instead giving it UTF-8 encoded text via a `char*` pointer that is merely being type-casted to `wchar_t*`. The character data itself that is being pointed at is still UTF-8, not UTF-16.

You need to instead actually convert the UTF-8 encoded `char` data to UTF-16 encoded `wchar_t` data, such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()` (or equivalent), eg:

```
struct user {
    wchar_t* name;
    // wchar_t name[16];
};

...

int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, json_name->valuestring, -1, NULL, 0);
users[i].name = (wchar_t*) malloc(len * sizeof(wchar_t));
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, json_name->valuestring, -1, users[i].name, len);

...

ListView_SetItemText(hWndListView, 2, 1, users[0].name);

...

free(users[i].name);
```

`TEXT("ササ")` works because you have  `UNICODE` defined in your project, so `TEXT()` prefixes its input string literal with the `L` prefix, ie `L"ササ"`, making it a proper UTF-16 encoded `wchar_t` string literal.

Comment: I am using cJSON which is UTF8 and somehow started thinking that the current standard is UTF8 everywhere, but it is not. JSON's default is UTF8 but 16 and 32 are also valid. Didn't know WinAPI is UTF16... thanks!

Comment: "*started thinking that the current standard is UTF8 everywhere, but it is not*" - no, in fact most platforms (well, at least most library APIs vs system APIs) are more standardized on UTF-16 rather than UTF-8. You will find that many 3rd party libraries prefer UTF-16 for text processing, as it is easier to work with, at the cost of more memory usage compare to UTF-8. UTF-8 is generally best for storage and communications, but not so much for text processing.